# Passing firebase data to another activity in form of ArrayList (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

The problem is that it always gives "List:NULL" Toast in MainActivity and list is not passed I suppose. Please help, trying for 2 days. Help me!!
I am confused as to how I should pass the ArrayList from Firebase database to my MainActivity.

Before doing the below thing, I tried to pass ArrayList in onCreate of Splash activity after it fetched from firebase but **myWebLinks** always came null when I used in onCreate except on **onDataChange** of ValueEventListener so I couldn't pass in next activity.

This is my SplashActivity.class

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "abcd";
//1 Firebase database object
//entry point for the app to access our database
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;

//2 is a class that reference a specific part of the database, references 'link' portion of DB
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

//To read from DB, attach ChildEventListener object to the reference. Allows to listen and have code triggered whenever
//changes occur on the node.
private ValueEventListener mValueEventListener;

private AVLoadingIndicatorView aviIV;

private ArrayList<WebLinks> mywebLinks;
public GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<WebLinks>> genericTypeIndicator;
private long seed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


    aviIV = findViewById(R.id.avi);
    aviIV.smoothToShow();

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("weblinks");


    if (mValueEventListener == null) {
        valueEventListener();
    }

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause: ");
    //14 Removing
    if (mValueEventListener != null) {
        mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(mValueEventListener);
        mValueEventListener = null;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mValueEventListener == null) {
        valueEventListener();
        mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);
    }
}

void valueEventListener() {

    final long[] value = {0};
    mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      /* This method is called once with the initial value and again whenever data at this location is updated.*/
            value[0] = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

            genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<WebLinks>>() {
            };

            mywebLinks = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator);

            seed = System.nanoTime();
            Collections.shuffle(mywebLinks, new Random(seed));
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "" + mywebLinks.get(0).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.i(TAG, "getWebLinksFirebaseeee: on");

            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("web_links", mywebLinks);
            startActivity(intent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    };
    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);

}
```

}

This is my MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView myWebView;
private WaveSwipeRefreshLayout mWaveSwipeRefreshLayout;
private Toolbar mtoolBar;
private ShineButton mFavBtn;
private BoomMenuButton leftBmb;

public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    leftBmb = (BoomMenuButton) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_left_bmb);
    mFavBtn = (ShineButton) findViewById(R.id.favBtn);
    mFavBtn.init(this);


    mtoolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(mtoolBar);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    }
    ArrayList<WebLinks> myList = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("web_links");

    if(myList==null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "LIST:NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "LIST:"+myList.get(1).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    initWebSettings();
    initSwipeRefresh();
    initLeftBtn();

}
```

This is my class

```
public class WebLinks implements Parcelable {

private String name;
private String link;

public WebLinks() {

}

public WebLinks(String webName, String webLink) {
    this.name = webName;
    this.link = webLink;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}


public static final Parcelable.Creator<WebLinks> CREATOR = new Creator<WebLinks>() {

    public WebLinks createFromParcel(Parcel source) {

        WebLinks fields = new WebLinks();

        fields.name = source.readString();

        fields.link = source.readString();


        return fields;

    }

    public WebLinks[] newArray(int size) {

        return new WebLinks[size];

    }

};


public int describeContents() {
    return 0;

}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {

    parcel.writeString(name);

    parcel.writeString(link);

  }

}
```

Comment: Is the list you're getting in `onDataChange()` null?

Comment: Try to send a simple string from onDataChange() with intents. If it goes through, then it means that your implementation of Parcelable is wrong.

Comment: Just query for the data again in the next activity.  If you have persistence enabled, the data will come from local cache, probably very quickly.